# EF Core 5 seeding with base class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
public abstract class Auditable
{
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public User CreatedUser { get; set; } = null!;
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
    public int? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public User? ModifiedUser { get; set; } = null!;
}
    
public class AuditableMap<TEntity> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> where TEntity : Auditable
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(t => t.Created).HasColumnType("timestamp without time zone");
        builder.Property(t => t.LastModified).HasColumnType("timestamp without time zone");
        builder.HasOne(t => t.CreatedUser).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.CreatedBy).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        builder.HasOne(t => t.ModifiedUser).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.LastModifiedBy).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}


public class User : IdentityUser<int>
    {
     ...Is navigation proprty need define here?
    }
```

Bank & branch:

```
public class Bank :Auditable,IEntity<int>
{
    ....
    public ICollection<Branch> Branches { get; set; } = new List<Branch>();
}

public class BankMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Bank>
{
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Bank> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("bank", schema: "public");
            builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);

             ... Removed

            //Data Seed

            builder.HasData(
                  new Bank() { Id = 1, Name = "B1", BaIN = "1", Code = "B1", DefaultAdminPassword = "Admin@123", RecieptName = "B1", Address1 = "A1", Address2 = "A2", TransferTypeId = 1, TransferFormatId = 1,NoOfDaysRetain=10, AdminModifyAT=true, LEDate= DateTime.Now.AddDays(100) ,CreatedBy= AuthorizationConstants.DEFAULT_SUPER_ADMIN_USERID,Created= DateTime.Now },
          );
    }
}

public class BranchMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Branch>
{
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Branch> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("branch", schema: "public");
            builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);
             ...

            builder.HasOne(b => b.Bank).WithMany(ba => ba.Branches).HasForeignKey(b => b.BankId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            // Data Seed
            builder.HasData(
                   new Branch() { Id = 2, Name = "B2", BrIN = "2", Code = "B2", RecieptName = "Br1", BankId = 1, BranchTypeId = 1, Address1 = "A1", Address2 = "A2", DefaultAgentPassword = "Agent@123", DefaultStaffPassword = "Staff@123", RecieptTypeId = 2, Created = DateTime.Now, CreatedBy = AuthorizationConstants.DEFAULT_SUPER_ADMIN_USERID }
          );
        }
}
```

When I run `add-migration`, I get this error:

```
add-migration init
Build started...
Build succeeded.
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Bank.CreatedUser' of type 'User'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidatePropertyMapping(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger) at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Infrastructure.NpgsqlModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ValidatingConvention.ProcessModelFinalized(IModel model)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelFinalized(IModel model)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelFinalized(IModel model)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.FinalizeModel()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Bank.CreatedUser' of type 'User'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
> PM>

Please let me know what is wrng with my code? This message i only getting only if i inherited Auditabe class in both class. If i am inherited Auditable in  any one entity (Bank/Branch) am not getting  error & also data migraated to db

Comment: `BankMap` should inherit `AuditableMap<Bank>`, override `Configure`, call `base.Configure` and then do its own things. Same for `BranchMap`.

Comment: Thank u very much @Ivan...I do the same..